# Position of "seem" in a sentence?

Tags: grammar, sentence

I recently came across a sentence which looks wierd to me.

The sentence is:

> Crazy it seems.

I think it had to be like below.

> It seems crazy.

If the first sentence is correct then clarify it please.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing ungrammatical about this:

> Crazy it seems.

Normally, we use subject + verb + object when we construct our sentences. But there is no rule that we *have* to, it's simply convention and a matter of style.

---

For example:

> Woe is me.

That's a common expression, but it's actually constructed as object + verb + subject. If we were to reverse it to match how we *normally* speak, it would sound odd:

> I am woe.

Or, perhaps:

> I am woeful.

As with all idioms, we are used to certain phrases being exactly as we've come to use them.

---

So, changing the order of the grammatical units might sound strange, but it's not actually ungrammatical. It's simply stylistically unusual.

The most common example of this, of course, is Yoda from the *Star Wars* movies, who used an object + subject + verb word order, and said things similar to this:

> Hungry I am.
>   Afraid you will be.
>   Do it you must.

---

However, you should probably stick to the normal subject + verb + object word order in normal use, and especially in formal writing.